# Algorithm find every child by idParent property

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have a table named Drinking.

Here is how it looks:

```
Name         idCategory  idParentCategory
drink            1              1
alcohol          2              1
nonalcohol       3              1
tea              5              3
juice            4              3
sparkling        6              4
nonsparkling     7              4
pepsi            8              6
schweppes        9              6
wine            10              2
beer            11              2
```

Now, the input is `idCategory`. As you can see there isn't property `idChildren`. What I am trying to do is find the ids of the children.

For example, if the input is 1, the output should be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11`.

Here is what I tried:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    List<Drinking> drinkingList= (from d in myEntities.Drinking
                              select d).ToList();
    foreach (var d in drinkingList)
    {
       if (d.Drinking2Reference.EntityKey != null)
       {
          s = c.Drinking2Reference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value.ToString();
          idPD = Int32.Parse(s);
          //get idParent
          if (idPC == idCat)
          {
             //if idParent is equal as the input, put this idCategory
             //in a list of integers.
             //Now, here comes the tricky part.
             //I should continue with this loop AND repeat this for
             //every child of idPC.
             //Where to put the call for this method?
             //Where to put the return statement?
             //Here is what I'm doing
             myMethod(idPC);
          }
          else
          {
             myMethod(idPC);
          }
       }

            }
}
```

My goal is to fill a list with the ids of the children and greatchildren

Comment: your question is not clear, and the provided code is merely a frame.. please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @amit My goal is to fill a list with the ids of the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void myMethod(int value)
{
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    List<Drinking> drinkingList= (from d in myEntities.Drinking
                          select d).ToList();
    foreach (var d in drinkingList)
    {
       if (d.Drinking2Reference.EntityKey != null)
       {
          if(d.idCategory == value)
             intList.Add(value);
          else {
             for(int i=0; i < intList.Count; i++) {
                if(intList.ElementAt(i) == d.idParentCategory)
                   intList.Add(d.idCategory);
             }
          }

       }
    }
    //Print numbers    
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I feel like it should work.  Feel free to comment if you catch something.  Also, the table has to be sorted by idParentCategory for this to work.  I will also say that with this situation I would recommend you look into using trees rather than a table.

Comment: It crashes at the foreach, it says Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot you can't change the list inside of a foreach that is using that list.  I changed the foreach into a regular for loop, should work now.